# If Changed is of type EventCallback, why can't we use ?. in Changed?.InvokeAsync()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I wonder why I cannot use `?.` (null conditional operator) in the following.

```
[Parameter] public EventCallback Changed {get; set;}
private void OnChanged()
{
  Changed?.InvokeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EventCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.eventcallback?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is a `struct` which are, [by design, non-nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#instantiation-of-a-structure-type).